# Adverb antonym of "allegedly"

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs, antonyms

How do you say using an adverb that you know something for sure?

For example: There are two people, John and Fred. John is suspected of a certain crime, but there is not enough evidence. He may have done it, but we can't prove it.

But there is evidence of Fred committing the crime.

How do I express "there is evidence that Fred committed the crime" in an adverb?

Sample sentence:

> Whereas John allegedly committed the crime, Fred X did it.

Comment: The precise construction of your example context steers us away from what I'd say is the most "natural" way of expressing it: ***Allegedly**, John committed the crime, **but evidently** Fred did it* (in practice, probably more emphatically, as *...evidently it was actually Fred who did it*).).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider *demonstrably*.

> **Demonstrably** *adverb*
>   In a way that is clearly apparent or capable of being logically proved.
>   ‘Now in these examples Black didn't do anything demonstrably wrong, yet he still ended up much worse.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/demonstrably)

Your sample sentence is then:

- Whereas John [only] allegedly [committed] the crime, Fred *demonstrably* did it.